# python 3.4 and mysql signals

Tags: python, mysql, signals

I am newbie in python and I encountered a problem when calling stored procedure which may generate a signal (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/signal.html). I cannot catch the signal as standard mysql exception (in contrary to .net environment (C#) which returned exception - as expected).

The problem is that the following store procedure returns error in mysql console as well as after calling "SHOW WARNINGS" but is not handled with python except syntax.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `TEST_CALL_ME_ERROR`;
DELIMITER //
CREATE DEFINER=root@localhost PROCEDURE TEST_CALL_ME_ERROR() DETERMINISTIC  

    MAIN_BLOCK: BEGIN

        SELECT 'THIS IS ONLY TEST' FROM DUAL;
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '01000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'I AM THE ERROR.', MYSQL_ERRNO = 1001;

END MAIN_BLOCK;
```

I tried pymysql and mysql from connector (with mysql c libraries).

```
try:
    connection = mysql.connect(host=localhost,
                               user=root,
                               passwd= ** ** **,
    db = "test", charset = 'utf8', port = 3306, raise_on_warnings = True)
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.callproc('TEST_CALL_ME_ERROR')
except Exception as e:
    print(e) # I expect to be here
```

Answer (score 1):

(Waking up the zombies!) Your problem lies in the fact that you are using a signal code starting with `01` (reserved for valid responses) hence your response is not an error therefore not handled as an exception in python

Comment: I haven't tested it, nonetheless it seems to me that the problem might be related to the state. However, a signal code starting with 01 is for a warning state (00 is for a successful ones). Additionally, I used a property "raise_on_warnings" and I expected that it will work like in the example provided by the documentation https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlconnection-raise-on-warnings.html.

Maybe if I used explicitly an error signal it would work like I expect and it would raise an exception.

Answer (score 0):

The stored procedure itself may not cause an error as it is syntactically correct (though its code outputs an error message). Possibly, printing its result will. You could test this theory by purposely writing an invalid syntax inside the stored procedure.

Consider any of the below iterations in the `Try` block:

```
results = cursor.callproc('TEST_CALL_ME_ERROR', ())
print(results)
```

OR

```
cursor.callproc('TEST_CALL_ME_ERROR', ())
results = cursor.fetchone()
print(results)
```

OR

```
cursor.execute('call TEST_CALL_ME_ERROR();')
results = cursor.fetchone()
print(results)
```